# How to evaluate NMF with a Trainingset?

Tags: machine-learning, evaluation, collaborative-filtering, factorization

What is the right way to test the predictions of Non-negative Matrix Factorization? Let´s say the dataset is a matrix with users and watched movies (without rating). First I split the matrix into a train and testset (40% testset). Then I factorize the training matrix with NMF. And then I take the test matrix, remove half of all movie entries, and see how good the real test matrix gets reconstructed.

What other ways of evaluation are used with NMF? Is there a better way than to remove movie entries in the testset?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is substantially the same question you asked last time. NNMF is only a means to implement collaborative filtering. Evaluating the fidelity of a low-rank matrix factorization is not a way to evaluate collaborative filtering results. The point of the low-rank factorization is that it is not exactly the same as the input.

You use measures like precision, recall, AUC, etc. which you already are familiar with. You do not split the test set further, no -- you're not making a cross-validation set or anything. So I don't know what this point is. Just use the test set as is as your set of "relevant" data.

Comment: I think there is something I don´t understand right, I´ve also read the myrrix "evaluating recommenders" site but I don´t know what I am doing wrong yet. If I have a prediction and a "relevant" data, I know how to use ROC etc. But which data should I use to make a prediction? If it is not "half of the movies" of a testset entry, what is it then?

Comment: You divide into a training and test set. You train on the training set, and test against the test set. You don't need to somehow divide the test set into subsets for some reason. Your test data are the "right answers", and your tests see whether the recommenders produce those items. This is a very problematic assumption to begin with for recommenders, but, still has some use.